# How to decide what should be bounded context

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-code, clean-architecture

I am trying to develop a demo application and confused while designing context.

Let's say we have three entity and their properties

```
User
    Id
    Email
Todo
    Questions
    Answers
        Value
        User (who answered)
Survey
    Questions
    Answers
        Value
        User (who answered)
```

Now I have 2 question about this

Now, I wonder what the best practice to define bounded context in such situation is.

According to the answer of first question, and assuming that User is used within both Todo and Survey, how we should define our context structure by User.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions like these are not answerable without an appropriate context, which you did not provide. We are left guessing at the use case or intended features. Why do questions and answers appear twice? Why does a todo item contain questions and answers? What problem are you trying to solve? What is the purpose of this applications? What features will be required? ... Software development is not a guessing game, it's an exercise in finding the answer - but we can't answer questions that center on the expectations of your customer/end user/product owner. How would we know?

Answer (score 1):

The bounded context is an environment where everything inside shares a common vocabulary, and these terms can be modeled in in common.  Interacting in between bounded contexts requires translation of terms and models.

A bounded context should be as large as possible provided all in it are able to use the same terminology, use the terms in the same way, and can share the same models for those terms.

Sometimes within a business two departments will use the same terms but the meaning of the terms and the depth and detail of the models of them is very different — this suggests separate bounded contexts.